# Is there any possibility to change the URL on mouse wheel event with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm beginner with ReactJS and I'm wondering if it's possible to change the URL when I scroll the mouse wheel up/down. The goal is to have a full page website that changes the URL while navigating through the sections. (reference: [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/))

I was thinking about to use the [react-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router) with [react-scroll-wheel-handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-wheel-handler) together. Is that possible any way? Does anyone see another better option?

Ps: I know the fullPage.js is also available for ReactJS, but I just wanna develop it by myself.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible with history.pushState() executed on scroll event.